# "Assembly will not load due to errors" Unity

Tags: c#, sql, unity3d

Делаю приложение на Unity, в котором нужно использовать базу данных, которая хранится на хостинге. При попытке добавить библиотеку `MySql.Data` в папку с проектом, чтобы использовать её в C#-скрипте, но после добавления .dll файла получаю ошибку:

```
Assembly 'Assets/Libraries/MySql.Data.dll' will not be loaded due to errors:
Unable to resolve reference 'Google.Protobuf'. Is the assembly missing or incompatible with the current platform? Reference validation can be disabled in the Plugin Inspector.
Unable to resolve reference 'Zstandard.Net'. Is the assembly missing or incompatible with the current platform? Reference validation can be disabled in the Plugin Inspector.
Unable to resolve reference 'K4os.Compression.LZ4.Streams'. Is the assembly missing or incompatible with the current platform? Reference validation can be disabled in the Plugin Inspector.
Unable to resolve reference 'BouncyCastle.Crypto'. Is the assembly missing or incompatible with the current platform? Reference validation can be disabled in the Plugin Inspector.
Unable to resolve reference 'Ubiety.Dns.Core'. Is the assembly missing or incompatible with the current platform? Reference validation can be disabled in the Plugin Inspector.
Unable to resolve reference 'Renci.SshNet'. Is the assembly missing or incompatible with the current platform? Reference validation can be disabled in the Plugin Inspector.
```

При это, если я добавлю `using MySql;` в любой C#-скрипт, то приложение просто не запускается.

Comment: [Assets/Plugins/*.dll](https://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/Special_Folder_Names_in_your_Assets_Folder) а не `Assets/Libraries/`

Comment: Libraries - директория, которую я сам создал.